# Not sure why my modal will not pop up on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I am starting coding for a hobby. I can't seem to get my modal to pop up on page load. I open a blank document and it loads just fine. Trying to load it on my friends homepage and nothing happens. I am working on Dreamweaver CC.

HTML:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Update</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Hello, we regret to inform you that we are closed today due to        currently upgrading our systems. We are working diligently on this matter. We want to continue to try and provide a fast and easy system for patients to be able to place their order. As always taking care of our patients and those in our community is our highest priority. We want to thank you for your loyalty and patience and we will try to resume business as quickly as possible. </h3>
            <h3>To stay updated with our current status and menu options follow us on Facebook.com/TheHumbleRoot and Instagram @humble_root. </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>We thank you for your patience</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
    display: block;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1
    }
}


    /* The Close Button */

    .close {
        color: white;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .modal-header {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5cb85c;
        color: white;
    }

    .modal-body {
        padding: 2px 16px;
    }

    .modal-footer {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5cb85c;
        color: white;
    }
```

JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the z-index, 1 is too low; to make sure to always put a big number on it to make sure it appears on front.

```
{
 z-index:999999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: block` in place of `display:"show"` on your modal class:

```
.modal {
     display: block;
}
```

`show` is not a valid CSS value for the `display` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: "show";` (which is wrong) on `.modal` to `display: block;`:

**[---> Working Fiddle here <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/q6u9o821/3/)**